# How to create a new function to simplify the code in Racket?

Tags: racket

I have two functions now, but most part of the function are the same. I am trying to make a new function that includes both of these functions. But I don't know how to unify the data of these functions. In particular, the two functions return different results. Do I need "if" in this case to distinguish the results of the two functions?

```
(check-expect
 (matching-x-posn
  '()
  10 (make-posn 0 0))
 (make-posn 0 0))

(check-expect
 (matching-x-posn
  (cons (make-posn 1 2) (cons (make-posn 3 4) '()))
  3 (make-posn 5 6))
 (make-posn 3 4))

(define (matching-x-posn lop desired-x default)
  (cond [(empty? lop) default]
        [(cons? lop)
         (if (= (posn-x (first lop)) desired-x)
             (first lop)
             (matching-x-posn (rest lop) desired-x default))]))

(define (matching-x-posn lox desired-num default)
  (find-first-match lox desired-num default)

(check-expect
     (string-with-length
      '()
      10)
     "no such string")
    
(check-expect
 (string-with-length
  (cons "hi" (cons "hello" (cons "aloha" '())))
  5)
 "hello")

(define (string-with-length los desired-length)
  (cond [(empty? los) "no such string"]
        [(cons? los)
         (if (= (string-length (first los)) desired-length)
             (first los)
             (string-with-length (rest los) desired-length))]))

(define (string-with-length lox desired-num)
  (find-first-match lox desired-num))

(check-expect (find-first-match
                   ('()
                    5
                    (make-posn 10 10))
                   ((make-posn 10 10)
                    "no such string")))

(check-expect (find-first-match
               ((cons "woo" (cons "yahoo" (cons "poog" '())))
                5
                (make-posn 5 9))
               (make-posn 5 9)
               "yahoo"))

(define (find-first-match lox desired-num default)
  (cond [(empty? lox)
         (or
          default
          "no such string")]
        [(cons? lop)
         (if (= (posn-x/string-length (first lox)) desired-num)
             (first lox)
             (matching-x-posn (rest lox) desired-num default))]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to simplify these two functions into one, but you will need operator [`lambda`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._lambda%29%29), which is provided by [Intermediate Student with Lambda](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html) language (or higher). Then you can write something like this:

```
(define (find-first-match lst predicate default)
  (cond ((empty? lst) default)
        ((predicate (first lst)) (first lst))
        (else (find-first-match (cdr lst) predicate default))))

(define (matching-x-posn lst desired-num default)
  (find-first-match lst
                    (lambda (pos) (= (posn-x pos) desired-num))
                    default))

(define (string-with-length lst desired-num default)
  (find-first-match lst
                    (lambda (str) (= (string-length str) desired-num))
                    default))

(check-expect
 (matching-x-posn '()
                  10
                  (make-posn 0 0))
 (make-posn 0 0))

(check-expect
 (matching-x-posn (list (make-posn 1 2) (make-posn 3 4))
                  3
                  (make-posn 5 6))
 (make-posn 3 4))

(check-expect
 (string-with-length '()
                     10
                     "no such string")
 "no such string")
    
(check-expect
 (string-with-length (list "hi" "hello" "aloha")
                     5
                     "no such string")
 "hello")
```