# How to combine two functions in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a new fucntion that works for two functions before. I am confused about the (cons/+) and (add-thanks/string-length) parts, since they are not the same kind of value.

```
(define (good-job lon)
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) '()]
    [(cons? lon)
     (cons
      (add-thanks (first lon))
      (good-job (rest lon)))]))
(define (add-thanks cost)
  (* cost 1.2))
(define (total-length los)
  (cond
    [(empty? los) 0]
    [(cons? los)
     (+
      (string-length (first los))
      (total-length (rest los)))]))
(define (good-length lox)
  (cond
    [(empty? lox) lox]
    [(cons? lox)
     (cons/+
      (add-thanks/string-length (first lox))
      (good-length (rest lox)))]))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "combine"?  There are *many* ways  to combine 2 functions into 1.

Comment: `add-thanks/string-length` and `cons/+` looks like they are supposed to be functions defined by you. Unfortunately, it's very hard to guess what they (and `good-length`) should accomplish.

Comment: On a side note, your `good-job` is a verbose `(map add-thanks lon)` and your `total-length` is a verbose `(apply + (map string-length lon))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513477/how-to-create-a-new-function-to-simplify-the-code-in-racket). It seems that you're both students of the same course, so I suggest you to join forces and next time, post only one well-thought question and not two similar.

Anyway, if you have instructions from teacher or from book, you should post them too, as well as `check-expect` tests. And you should also comment your code, to make clear what are `lon`, `los` or `lox`.

Used language is [Intermediate Student with Lambda](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html).

```
(define (good-length join-fn
                     element-fn
                     join-fn-last-element
                     lox)
  (cond
    [(empty? lox) join-fn-last-element]
    [(cons? lox)
     (join-fn
      (element-fn (first lox))
      (good-length join-fn
                   element-fn
                   join-fn-last-element
                   (rest lox)))]))

(define (add-thanks cost)
  (* cost 1.2))

(define (good-job lon)
  (good-length cons add-thanks '() lon))

(define (total-length los)
  (good-length + string-length 0 los))
```